# What is the difference between the two statements below?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
 [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

They are used in the context below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window


    //   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
     [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    IntroViewController *introViewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Lets place introViewController in navController
    UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:introViewController];

    //Now lets display it 
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [navController release];
    [introViewController release];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [iOS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/):

**rootViewController**

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window.
>   Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the window has an existing view
>   hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are
>   installed.

**addSubview**

> This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver,
>   which is its new superview.
>
> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

So we can say that the main difference is that setting rootViewController destroys all the previous views contained in the `UIWindow`, and using addSubView: only adds an `UIView` on top.

Answer (score 0):

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

This statement is wrong because window is  a container you don't have any root controller there.

SubView:
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

```
Here you are adding the tabBarController as a subview which will add your windows container. And this is the right way to create the tab bar controller.
```